# Is there any way to get the size of the partially loaded content of a file at a particular time through C++ program?

Tags: c++, file

I am not opening a file in the file stream . There is a "browse" button , after clicking on that it gives you the option to choose a file ,like all the other browse buttons. Then the file will be opened in the application which is already defined to open that kind of file .For example pdf file will be opened in adobe , .txt will be opened in notepad(or notepad++ or any other text editor which is set to open .txt files) . I want to get how much content of that file has been loaded at a perticular time.Is there any way to get the size of the partially loaded content of that file?

Comment: As far as I know, all read operations return the number of bytes read in that operation. so check the return value. Otherwise post more details/ code so we can better help you

Comment: What do you mean "opening a file in the predefined application". You mean you're telling the default app for .txt files to open "foo.txt", and you want to know how far that app has gotten into reading "foo.txt"?

Comment: Loaded to memory? What is a final purpose of this? It seems you're going to create something like a progress bar for file reading operation. Is it so?

Answer (score 1):

I will make the following assumptions:

- your "predefined application" is actually a library that is not under your control, but is reading a file for you
- you want to know how far the read pointer for the file has advanced
- you have access to the underlying object that represents the file (either a `FILE *` or a `ifstream`, a POSIX file descriptor, or a Windows file `HANDLE`) that the "predefined application" is using

If you opened the file with `fopen` for reading, you would use `ftell` on the `FILE *`.

```
FILE *infile;
//...
long position = ftell(infile);
```

If you have an `ifstream`, use the `tellg` method.

```
std::ifstream infile;
//...
long position = infile.tellg();
```

If the file was opened for read with `open`, you could use `lseek` on the file descriptor.

```
int infile;
//...
long position = lseek(infile, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

If the file is opened for reading on Windows with `OpenFile`, you would use `SetFilePointer` on the `HANDLE`.

```
HANDLE infile;
//...
long position = SetFilePointer(infile, 0, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Sure, this will work… Then again, if he's reading the whole thing into memory, he must already know how much he's read, or he has no idea what pointer to pass to the next fread/read/etc. So he could just do (nextBufferPos - startOfBuffer) and get the exact same effect…

Comment: @abarnert: It depends on what he means by "predefined application", I'll clarify my post. Thanks and regards

Comment: Yes, I really have no idea what he's asking, which is why I didn't even try to provide an answer… good luck with your valiant effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++ streams, there you can use the [`tellg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg) function to get the position in the file.

Note that this returns the position relative to the size of the stream character. For example, reading ten characters of `istream` (which uses `char`) then `tellg` will report ten, but reading ten characters from a `wistream` (that uses `wchar_t`) then the reported amount will be either twenty or forty depending on the size of `wchar_t`.